# Detecting whether vim supports functions

Tags: functions

I have a function definition in my `.vimrc`. This `.vimrc` is sufficient to demonstrate the problem I'm asking about:

```
function! Greet()
    echo "hello"
endfunction
```

I want to be able use the same `.vimrc` with a version of vim configured with

```
--with-features=tiny
```

I don't expect the function to be defined, but I don't want error messages on startup.

Currently, if I run a tiny vim, I get:

```
Error detected while processing /home/kst/.vimrc:
line    1:
E319: Sorry, the command is not available in this version: function! Greet()
line    2:
E319: Sorry, the command is not available in this version:     echo "hello"
line    3:
E319: Sorry, the command is not available in this version: endfunction
Press ENTER or type command to continue
```

I'm looking for something like:

```
if has("function")
    function! Greet()
        echo "hello"
   endfunction
endif
```

but that doesn't do the job because `has()` doesn't recognize `"function"`. (The result is that the function definition is disabled even for versions of vim that support functions.)

I didn't see anything obvious in the documentation for `has()`, and web searches with the word "function" give me a lot of irrelevant hits.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The problem is that "tiny" is missing the `+eval` feature and that's what prevents it from seeing your function definitions.

So you could try something like:

```
if has('eval')
    function! Greet()
        echo "hello"
    endfunction
endif
```

But it turns out you can go even simpler than that, as [`:help no-eval-feature`](https://vimhelp.org/eval.txt.html#no-eval-feature) suggests:

> When the `+eval` feature was disabled at compile time, none of the expression
>   evaluation commands are available.  To prevent this from causing Vim scripts
>   to generate all kinds of errors, the `:if` and `:endif` commands are still
>   recognized, though the argument of the `:if` and everything between the `:if`
>   and the matching `:endif` is ignored.  Nesting of `:if` blocks is allowed, but
>   only if the commands are at the start of the line.  The `:else` command is not
>   recognized.

So you can simply use:

```
if 1
    function! Greet()
        echo "hello"
    endfunction
endif
```

(I strongly suggest adding a comment to indicate why you're using `if 1`, why it makes sense, why it's needed!)

Looking inside `$VIMRUNTIME/defaults.vim`, there's a snippet there that uses a hack to only run a command whenever `+eval` is not available. Adapting that to your specific case:

```
" Use a trick to break out when the
" +eval feature is missing.
silent! while 0
    finish
silent! endwhile

function! Greet()
    echo "hello"
endfunction
```

If `+eval` is missing, it won't recognize the `while` statement and will `finish`, breaking out of the script and skipping everything that follows.

When `+eval` is present, the `while 0` block will be skipped, since the condition is false.

The [`:help no-eval-feature`](https://vimhelp.org/eval.txt.html#no-eval-feature) section also mentions this technique (with a different command as example) and explains it:

> When the `+eval` feature is available the command is skipped because of the
>   `while 0`.  Without the `+eval` feature the `while 0` is an error, which is
>   silently ignored, and the command is executed.

Comment: you can also use `:if 1` tiny vim will not read anything in between this.

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt I was in doubt whether tiny vim would ignore `:if` as a whole or just (complex) expressions... Why does the `silent! while 0` work then? Is it because it's `while` and not `if` so vim-tiny doesn't ignore it? Why the `silent!`?

Comment: the `if 1` is the documented way how to make vim.tiny skip eval code (don't ask me where this is documented, don't find it currently) and this is also what defaults.vim used initially. The thing why `silent! while 0` was needed, was because we wanted to run a piece of code only in tiny vim, but not a vim that has `eval` feature. So eval vims would skip that, while tiny vim does read it. Since tiny vim do not understand `while`, we needed `:silent!` to not show any error message.

Comment: see also this issue: https://github.com/vim/vim/issues/1630 that lead to that part of the code.

Comment: and the related help topic is `:h no-eval-feature`

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt Both `if has('eval')` and `if 1` work. I think the former works just because the expression is ignored. I'll use `if 1`.

Comment: Thanks @ChristianBrabandt and Keith! I'll update the answer to include more deatils (in particular the great reference to `:h no-eval-feature`!) Most likely later this evening or tomorrow. Thanks again for the great discussion!

Comment: Confirmed with tiny, small, normal, big, and huge builds. The tiny and small builds don't support functions, and I don't get a diagnostic on startup. The normal, big, and huge builds do support functions, and the function is defined correctly.

Comment: Updated to include background on `:help no-eval-feature`, thanks @ChristianBrabandt for mentioning it!